# How do I run a batch file that automatically runs the .exe file when it gets stopped?

Tags: batch-file

can someone help me out with this?

How do I run a batch file that automatically runs the .exe file when it gets stopped?

Answer (score 1):

You can run an inf looping batch like the below to constantly check:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
tasklist | findstr "theexe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto theexe
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto start
:theexe
cls
start /d "path" the.exe
goto start
```

This will constantly check to see if `theexe` is running and if it's not run it.

---

Simplified version thanks to Psycogeek

```
@echo off
:start
start /d "path" /w the.exe
goto start
```